# Error during installation of Ionic on Cloud9 Workspace

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, cloud9-ide

I was trying to install ionic on my c9.io workspace (following this simple tutorial https://docs.c9.io/docs/ionic) and I came up with the following error:

```
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current:     {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"3.3.10"})
move:hoek → lifecycle

npm WARN install:sigmund@1.0.1 ENOENT: no such file or directory,
rename     '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/co    rdova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-    gyp/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/sigmund' ->     '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/si    gmund'
move:browserify

Killed
```

And the installation did not complete.

It is a new workspace, running npm v3.3.10.
I've tried the installation with node 0.10, 0.12 and 4.11 (using nvm) without success.

Could someone please advise me on that one?

Here's the screenshot of what is going on:
[image: Error during ionic installation at cloud9 IDE]

Thanks!

Comment: which node js version u r using

Comment: @RoshanBharti I was using node 4.1.1. I changed to 0.12.6 as well and it finally worked. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try to install Node JS version 0.12.6 and after that try to install:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

It worked for me.

Comment: That worked for me as well. Just to make it clearer for others, after installing a different version of Node, I used nvm to change the active version easily.